# JW Player - Video works in chrome, not firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

See [working link](http://www.888behindthescenes.com/test).

On the homepage I have two videos (#intro_video & #video_container) which under chrome I have no problems, but in firefox and IE the video doesn't play. It's loading the preview image but when you click play it tries to load for a moment and then goes back to the preview.

I have tried using Jquery Flash (loads #intro_video):

```
var so = new SWFObject('/swf/player.swf','ply','670','300','9','#000000');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
so.addVariable('playlistfile','/videos/home.rss');
so.addVariable('playlist','left');
so.addVariable('playlistsize','240');
so.addVariable('bufferlength','15');
so.addVariable('plugins','fbit-1');
so.addVariable('dock','true');
so.addVariable('skin','/swf/modieus.swf');
so.addVariable('lightcolor','CC3399');
so.write('video_container');
```

and the recommended javascript (#video_container) from the wizard with no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // intro video
    $('#intro_video').flash({
        src: '/swf/player.swf', width: 367, height: 260,
        flashvars: {
            allowfullscreen: 'true', 
            allowscriptaccess: 'always', 
            wmode: 'opaque',
            file: 'http://www.888behindthescenes.com/media/videos/intro2.flv', 
            image: '/images/sized/media/videos/previews/intro-370x228.jpg',
            skin: '/swf/modieus.swf', 
            backcolor: '000000', 
            frontcolor: 'FFFFFF', 
            lightcolor: 'CC3399'
        }
    });

});
```

The flash is loading fine, just not the videos. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've tried both absolute and relative paths as well...

Comment: what is in 'serialFlow.inc' in httpdocs folder?

Comment: is the problem still there?... FYI, the videos here in mine are working fine... in all my browsers...

Comment: Yes... still there, do these work for you? http://www.888behindthescenes.com/test

Comment: serialFlow.inc is used to track download links or something, not exactly sure. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by adding:

```
AddType video/x-flv .flv
```

to htaccess.