# JW Player not working properly in Firefox and IE9

Tags: jquery, html, video, browser, jwplayer

I'm having a problem getting JW Player to work properly with Firefox and IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/2rzyB/

The problem is that where the player is supposed to show up I see nothing in Firefox. In IE I see a really screwed up size.

It works perfectly on every other browser.

Comment: There was a very similar issue reported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121871/jw-player-video-works-in-chrome-not-firefox-or-ie

Comment: Did you have to drop that dynamic resizing? Do you still do a resize at all? If so, can you share what worked?

Comment: Yeah I ended up having to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem turned out to be with the way I was dynamically resizing the player when the window was resized.