# jwPlayer resize issue in Firefox and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script> 
   <div id="myElement"">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "video/mosk.mp4",
        image: "img/fwd22group/mosk.jpg",
        width: "880px",
        height: "500px"
    });
</script>
```

When I use this code in chrome it's working fine but in Firefox and Opera, it doesn't work.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256225/jw-player-not-working-properly-in-firefox-and-ie9) question it depends on width and height.

What should I do here for fixing this issue?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution just need to remove px

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "video/mosk.mp4",
        image: "img/fwd22group/mosk.jpg",
        width: "880",
        height: "500"
    });
</script>
```